# Facebook og:image is wrong when sharing ONLY

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Looking into the source of the page the og:image is correct, however everytime you try and share the image with Facebook is uses the large banner on the page - http://www.forefrontproperty.co.uk/property-full-details?profileID=100117000843

Using Facebook to debug, it shows the correct og:image too, but next shows correct when trying to search. I have left it for weeks hoping cache would be cleared and have manually cleared cache and still get the same issues.

My question is, why ?

Secondly, can I force Facebook not to follow that link, or is there a way of not making is scan-able by Facebook.